# Proving Binomial identity involving algebraic expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

How did i prove

$$\frac{\binom{n}{0}}{x}-\frac{\binom{n}{1}}{x+1}+\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{x+2}-\cdots \cdots +(-1)^n\frac{\binom{n}{n}}{x+n}=\frac{n!}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n)}$$

what i try

$$\sum^{n}_{r=0}(-1)^r\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{x+r}=\int^{1}_{0}\sum^{n}_{r=0}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}t^{x+r-1}dt$$

$$\begin{align}=\int^{1}_{0}t^{x-1}\sum^{n}_{r=0}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}t^{r}dt
=\int^{1}_{0}t^{x-1}(1-t)^ndt\end{align}$$

Comment: Continuing further $$\int_0^1 t^{x-1} \left(\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom nr t^r \right) dt=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^n dt =B(x,n+1)$$

Comment: And now you can finish by using the usual relation between the Beta and Gamma functions and the usual recursion for the Gamma function.

Comment: thanks Diagamma got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible way is as follows:

Multiplying by $\prod_{i=0}^n(x+i)$ gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\prod_{\stackrel{i=0}{i\neq k}}^n(x+i) = n!$$

On the left side is a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$. So we only need to check the identity at $n+1$ points. A good choice for that are the zeros of $\prod_{i=0}^n(x+i)$:

$$P(-k)  = (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\underbrace{\prod_{\stackrel{i=0}{i\neq k}}^n(i-k)}_{=(-1)^k\cdot k!\cdot (n-k)!} = n!$$

So, we are done.